# Ideal structure (or possibilities) for large sparse matrix and its metadata

Tags: python, metadata, dataframe, sparse-matrix

I am working with a sparse matrix of about 260k rows, 3M columns and 26M non-zero values (stored in Matrix Market format). I also have JSON files that describe the metadata for each row and column. I need to perform matrix operations over this matrix, namely matrix products, although other operations will be required most surely. I have been working with my matrix   and with my dictionaries (coming from the JSONs), each dictionary links the row/col index to its metadata value. It is not ideal, although it works.

I do wonder, is there a better option out there? I am aware of Pandas/Dato dataframes but it seems to me that the matrix part (and its operations) is relegated somehow. I have been following a little bit the blaze project (Dask, xray, mainly these out-of-core technologies). I want to know what is the standard way (or the most adequate way) to deal with this scenario.

Any insight is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of `pandas` has "[sparse](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/sparse.html)" datastructures, including `DataFrame`, `Series`, and `Panel`, which can be compressed on *any* common value, including `NaN`, not just 0. Pandas is supported behind the scenes by [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org) and [optionally](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html#optional-dependencies) by [`scipy`](http://www.scipy.org), which has the [`scipy.sparse`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) module for directly working with mathematically sparse (mainly 0-filled) matrices. "Sparse" Pandas objects have an [experimental API](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/sparse.html#interaction-with-scipy-sparse) to convert to `scipy.sparse` objects, as well.